# MySQL regexp against an array of terms

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, regex

I have the following query which searches a column for a given string

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name REGEXP '$search_term'
```

Is it possible to search that column to see whether it contains one (or more) words from an array?

Comment: have you looked at find_in_set? what does $search_term contain?

Comment: Why not use several regexp or instr conditions combined by OR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to find one or more words

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(column_name, 'word1,word2,word3')
```

what find in set does is it looks at the value inside a column and compares it to the values in your comma separated string.

### CAUTION!!!!!

don't put a variable directly in a query like that.. it makes you VULNERABLE to SQL INJECTION attacks!!!! you should look into using prepared statements.. look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for help with sql injection

### NOTE:

if you dont have a way to get a comma separated list of words you can use GROUP_CONCAT().. I'll provide a demo below using both ways.

here is a [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1dda/7)

### QUERY:

```
SET @word_list := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(words) FROM test where id IN(1, 3, 4));

SELECT @word_list;
```

after assigning the string to @word_list you want to see whats in it so I select it.

### OUTPUT:

```
'whatever,maybe,final'
```

now lets run the find in set query with the user defined variable and then again with just the string.

### QUERY:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(words, @word_list );
```

### OUTPUT:

```
+----+----------+
| id | words    |
+----+----------+
| 1  | whatever |
| 3  | maybe    |
| 4  | final    |
+----+----------+
```

### WRITING IT IN:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(words, 'whatever,maybe,final')
```

### OUTPUT:

```
+----+----------+
| id | words    |
+----+----------+
| 1  | whatever |
| 3  | maybe    |
| 4  | final    |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: Very nice, didn't know about it +1

Comment: @Fede thanks! I re-wrote a ton of my SQL queries when I came across this :) it's very useful! (especially when used with `group_concat()` )